# Difficulty Embedding Office Add-In in normal.dotm Template

Tags: office-js, office-addins

I'm trying to embed an Office Add-In into the normal.dotm template using a custom executable that takes parameters like GUID and version. The executable works smoothly for new documents, but when it comes to documents based on normal.dotm, the embedded add-in doesn't load.

Here's my process:

I [followed article](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Office-OOXML-EmbedAddin)to create an executable that embeds an add-in.
The executable works fine for custom documents(dotx, docx, dotm etc), but not for normal.dotm.
The add-in doesn't load in documents based on normal.dotm.
Queries:

Is it possible to embed an Office Add-In into normal.dotm using this method, so the add-in automatically loads for new files?
Are there limitations when modifying normal.dotm or specific concerns with its default nature?
Could alternative approaches ensure my add-in loads by default in normal.dotm-based documents?

I have verified that add-in gets embedded to normal.dotm file by renaming to zip and checking the webextensions , but it still doesn't show when I open a new document.